# How to execute a script when a list box option is selected in javascript?

Tags: javascript, listbox

I need to know how to execute a script when a user selects an option from my list box. My current code (though this is probably the wrong approach is:

```
<form>
    Character Name: <input type="text" name="charname">
</form>
    Server Region: <select id="serverloc">
        <option value="4">US</option>
        <option value="Oceanic">Oceanic</option>
    </select>

<script>
   var serverloc = document.getElementById(4);
   if ( serverloc == "Oceanic" ) {
      document.Write("it Worked!")
   }
</script>
```

Comment: check http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: It's `document.write()`, lowercase `w`, and you should not use it after the page has fully loaded.

Comment: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_events/ and http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/select.shtml should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Server Region: <select id="serverloc">
    <option value="4">US</option>
    <option value="Oceanic">Oceanic</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
var select = document.getElementById('serverloc');
select.onchange = function(){ alert('yay'); };
```